# How to get Average Disk Response Time in Linux/Redhat through SNMP

Tags: network-programming, snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

Actually I am developing system monitoring tools using different opens source such as InfluxDb, Telegraf, Grafana and SNMP(Simple Network Management Protocol).

I am enabling SNMP in the different linux or Redhat systems and fetching the systems statics through Telegraf and storing data into influxDB.

So here I am using telegraf as a agent master(collecting data from multiple systems) and SNMP as a agent and got CPUs, Ram/swap, Disk usage, Network packets etc through Mibs.

I am trying to monitor **Average Disk Response time (wait+service time)** as well.

I got **UCD-DISKIO-MIB** but its providing some row data.

So the question is how to calculate average response time using those data.

Comment: I think your question is missing important information - try to create a MVCE for us - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and what you are trying to achieve in general.  Maybe there is a better way to do it.